# cy.get() could not find a registered alias when using before hook

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
describe("Share Link", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.generateLink().then(response => {
      let url = response.meeting_shared_link.split("/");
      cy.wrap(url[url.length - 1]).as("link");
    });


  describe("when I turn on link sharing", () => {
    // This works.  Changing it to a before hook breaks it.
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.get("@link").then(link =>
        cy.toggleLinkSharing({ link: link })
      );
  });  
});
```

I am currently generating an alias - @link - in my first `beforeEach` hook, and then accessing it in the next beforeEach hook which is nested in a describe.

My problem is that I need the latter hook to be a `before`, rather than a `beforeEach`.

When I modify it to a before hook - it is unable to find the alias "link".  ***Why?***

I understand that aliases are cleared between each test, hence the need for the first `beforeEach` hook - but why isn't it available inside a `before` hook?

**Edit:**. I *think*, it may be because the latter defined `before` hook triggers before the first `beforeEach` - in which case, the alias didn't yet exist.  If this is the case - it's not intuitive.  The before hook should only fire after the beforeEach since it's nested in another describe.

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#hooks -> Cypress inherits their before/beforeEach hooks from Mocha, so your issue about the intuitiveness of the names lies with them. FWIW, in their docs, they do explicitly lay out the order of the hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the outer `beforeEach()` to `before()`, and preserve the alias between tests with `beforeEach(function() { cy.wrap(this.link).as('link') })`

It works because `this.link` is not cleared between tests, even though the alias `@link` ***is*** cleared.

```js
describe("Share Link", () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.wrap('my-url').as("link");
    console.log('Outer before')
  });

  describe("when I turn on link sharing", () => {

    beforeEach(function() { cy.wrap(this.link).as('link') })  // preserve the alias

    before(() => {
      cy.get("@link").then(link => {
        console.log('Inner before', link)
      })
    })

    it('1st test', () => {
      cy.get('@link').then(link => console.log('1st test', link))
    })

    it('2nd test', () => {
      cy.get('@link').then(link => console.log('2nd test', link))
    })
  })  
})
```

Console output

```js
Outer beforeEach
Inner before my-url
1st test my-url
2nd test my-url
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.link and try out.

```
 describe("Share Link", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.generateLink().then(response => {
      let url = response.meeting_shared_link.split("/");
       cy.wrap(url[url.length - 1]).as("link");
        });

    describe("when I turn on link sharing", () => {
   // This works.  Changing it to a before hook breaks it.
     beforeEach(() => {
    cy.toggleLinkSharing(this.link)
     });  
      });
```

Reference here:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context

Comment: @s89_ Sorry I  copy pasted wrong code previosuly, Edited it now. If you have used as instead of @ you can also use this keyword to get it